# MATLAB: compare elements in arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, contains

suppose there are arrays A and B, both of which can have any arbitrary numbers and size. for example

```
A=[1 2 3]
B=[4 8 52 7 10]
```

i was wondering if there was any way to check if any of the elements in A are contained in B without using a loop? Once again, the numbers and size of the array will be arbitrary so i can't hard code it. Any help and input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You mean like this:

```
A=[1 2 3]; B=[4 8 52 7 10] 
ismember(A,B)
```

ans =

```
0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to @NasserM.Abbasi: ismember will work regardless shapes and sizes, it is always element-wise. So if you have `A=[1 2; 3 4]` and `B=[1 3; 4 2; 1 2]`,
then ismember will return :

```
ismember(A,B);         % -> [1 1; 1 1] due to element-wise membership check
ismember(A,B, 'rows'); % -> [1 0] since it checks row-wise.
```

use ismember carefully according to the possible shapes in `A` and `B`.